# How do you make PHP read POP emails?

Tags: php, email

I'm looking for a very simple PHP email reader (I use "reader" loosely - I really only want to be able to perform database operations on each email). I'd prefer it to use POP, but I could settle with IMAP if I have to. I know PHP supports these, but I'm having trouble finding codes with the bare minimum that I'm looking for.
All I would like to be able to do is to extract the "to" address, the "from" address, the subject, the body, and the date/time sent. I do not need anything else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POP is usually only used when you want to download-and-delete messages off the server. If you want to keep the messages on the server, you may as well just use IMAP.

Either way, you can use the [IMAP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) for PHP. Technically, it supports both IMAP *and* POP (as well as NNTP), but not all capabilities/functions are available for POP.

And what you want to do is pretty simple. Just look at the PHP documentation for [`imap_headerinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php) and [`imap_body()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php). There's no need to find a script or "codes" that do exactly what you want. It would be quicker to write the code yourself.